# DynamoDB converting ZonedDateTime in nested object

Tags: java, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I'm switching from MongoDB to DynamoDB on a project. Now I'm trying to store this Post object in the db. I'm using the DynamoDBTypeConverter to convert the ZonedDateTime to a String, as DynamoDB doesn't support ZonedDateTime.

That works fine, but when I'm adding a ZonedDateTime field in the Comment object and try to convert it too it doesn't work. I've tried adding a converter to the Comment class, and tried using the converter in the Post class for Comment, but nothing seems to work. Is there a way to convert a field in a nested object for DynamoDB?

`com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: Cannot marshall type class java.time.ZonedDateTime without a custom marshaler or @DynamoDBDocument annotation.`

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Post")
public class Post {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private String postNumber;
    private ZonedDateTime date;
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = ZonedDateTimeConverter.class)
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public ZonedDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "comments")
    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }


static public class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, ZonedDateTime> {

    @Override
    public String convert(final ZonedDateTime time) {
        return time.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime unconvert(final String stringValue) {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(stringValue);
    }
}



@DynamoDBDocument
public class Comment {

private String commentNumber;
@NotNull
private User user;
private ZonedDateTime date;

@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = ZonedDateTimeConverter.class)
@DynamoDBAttribute
public ZonedDateTime getDate(){
    return this.date;
}

static public class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, ZonedDateTime> {

    @Override
    public String convert(final ZonedDateTime time) {
        return time.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime unconvert(final String stringValue) {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(stringValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the `PostDTO` in the annotation for the date in `Comment`?  Either way, I’d recommend making the type converter into its own top-level public class.

Comment: Sorry, the  `PostDTO` in the annotation was just a mistake, it not actually in my code. Thanks for the advice though